# Проблема обновления ссылки на службу

Tags: c#, wcf

После обновлении ссылки на службу, все используемые классы через ссылку становятся не доступными. 
Раз 30 уже попытался обновить ничего не получатся.
VS 2015
.NET 4.

Другие проекты в решении прекрасно обновляют ссылки на службу, кроме этого.
Я очень много времени потратил на решение этой проблемы, ничего не нашел.
[image: Скрин]

Как ее обновить, чтобы работало?

Comment: а как вы ее создавали до обновления? Я сильно подозреваю, что добавляли ссылку на службу ручной генерацией по wsdl и xsd файлам, которые могли быть предоставлены не через сервис, а как-то еще, архивом например. Сервис может, но не обязан предоставлять свои метаданные посторонним. Если это ваш сервис, то проверяйте, что в его конфигурации есть привязка mex, для обмена мета-данными.

Comment: mex привязка есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В клиентском приложении была ошибочно добавлена директива  `using` на библиотеку с типами, которые уже получены через ссылку на службу. 
После попытки обновления ссылки на службу, компилятор выдает большое количество ошибок.

Решение: удаление директивы `using` на библиотеку. И обновление ссылки на службу. Обновление прошло успешно.